# How to write Junit test cases for pojo classes if there is no implementation class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, pojo

I'm working in a project. In that project we have some pojo classes where we read the data from XML file. Now I have to write Junit test cases for that but there is no implementation of those pojo classes. How can I write the test cases for those pojo classes ?

(There are so many classes are there among them I'll mention one)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Tostring
@XmlAccessor(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AdditionalAddress{
    @XmlElement(name ='PersonalInfo")
    private PersonalInfo personalInfo;
    @XmlElement(name ='AddressType")
    private String addressType;
}
```

I need to know how to write Junit test cases for these pojo classes?

Answer (score 1):

**This is bad programming practice.** *We should never write unit test cases for POJO, Entity & Exception classes.* These classes should be covered by Integration Test cases or other Unit Test cases like Service Classes, Controllers etc.

Comment: Yes but imagine: you have a 3rd party xml/schema, of which you(r services/classes) use/need only few portions... Quality manager says: Increase coverage! ..then??

Comment: I think we should never write test cases to increase code coverage or make managers happy :)  If code coverage is not increasing by other genuine unit test cases or integration test cases (ideally it should) then better to exclude classes from the code quality tools like SonarQube.